# script to rotate apache weblog

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, bash, cron, logrotate

I am looking for a script that would rotate weblogs on apache. I'd like to schedule the script over cron so it could run periodically and rotate access_log and error_log for all websites on the server.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 5):

install and configure **logrotate**

- an howto: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/
- man page:  http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Answer (score 4):

Another good tool is [Cronolog](http://cronolog.org/)

> cronolog is a simple filter program
>   that reads log file entries from
>   standard input and writes each entry
>   to the output file specified by a
>   filename template and the current date
>   and time. When the expanded filename
>   changes, the current file is closed
>   and a new one opened. cronolog is
>   intended to be used in conjunction
>   with a Web server, such as Apache, to
>   split the access log into daily or
>   monthly logs.

Example Configuration:

```
 CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /web/logs/%Y/%m/%d/access.log"
 ErrorLog  "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /web/logs/%Y/%m/%d/errors.log"
```

Will produce and rotate logs automaticlly to:

```
 /web/logs/2009/09/25/access.log
 /web/logs/2009/09/25/errors.log
```